# Create a flattened representation of an class based on its MRO

Tags: python

How would I create a flattened representation of a class that is composed of multiple base classes/mixins.  Is there a library for doing such a thing? For example:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def a(self):
        return 

class Bar(object):
    def b(self):
        return

class Baz(Foo, Bar):
    pass
```

I want to be able to create a text representation of the flattened class that would look like this:

```py
class Baz(object):
    def a(self):
        return

    def b(self):
        return
```

The idea would be to create a text editor plugin (ST2 in my case) to allow the user to right-click on a class name and select an option to have a tab open with the flattened class displayed for reference.

Of course the tool would need to be smart enough to treat super calls as basically includes.

Comment: How would you want it to display overridden methods?  Like what if both Foo and Baz define the same method (with Baz overriding the Foo version)?

Comment: If two base classes share the same method name, use MRO to resolve which method takes precedence.

Comment: If by "includes" you mean you want the source code of inherited methods to be literally pasted into the subclass methods, that is a tall order.  It could probably be done, but you will have to use the `inspect` module to get the source code of each function and then paste together the strings yourself (handling any indentation mismatches, etc.)

Comment: Indeed, hence why I'm asking if it's already been done so I don't pull out the remaining of my hair :)

Comment: The "includes" feature is a *very* tall order since the classes don't need to be defined in the same files -- As such, they don't even share the same global scope.  If a superclass references a variable in the global scope which isn't in the current scope, what should be displayed for that variable?  Just displaying the variable's name seems confusing at best ...

Comment: This still seems to me to be a trivial exercise, and I've updated my answer below to show a complete implementation.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, most tools that do this do it by executing the code and interrogating the defined class.  A simple implementation might be:

```
import inspect
import textwrap

def print_def(cls):
    print('class %s:' % cls.__name__)
    for name, member in inspect.getmembers(cls):
        if not name.startswith('__') and member is not None:
            source = inspect.getsource(member)
            source = textwrap.dedent(source)
            for l in source.split('\n'):
                print('    %s' % l)
```

To illustrate this, assume that the file you're interrogating contains the following definitions:

```
class A:
    def a_method(self):
        self.a = 4
        return self.a

    def overridden(self):
        print('This is A')

class B:
    def b_method(self):
        print([1, 2, 3])
        return 4

class C(A, B):
    def c_method(self):
        pass

    def overridden(self):
        print('This is C')
```

Then:

```
>>> vars = {}
>>> execfile('myfile.py', {}, vars)
>>> print_def(vars['C'])
class C:
    def a_method(self):
        self.a = 4
        return self.a

    def b_method(self):
        print([1, 2, 3])
        return 4

    def c_method(self):
        pass

    def overridden(self):
        print('This is C')
```

You'd need to decide what you want it to do with members such as `__repr__` and `__doc__`, this implementation just ignores them.